# Disambiguation of 'ub' and 'v' in acronyms?

Tags: pronunciación

If `V` is pronounced `uve`, then would it sound the same as `UB` (`u-be`)? If that is the case, how do speakers disambiguate this possible confusion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A pause denotes a separate letter:

VIH: ube, i , hache
UBA: u, be a

People often use whole words to denote letters when there is noise, or when talking over the phone:

Valencia, Italia, Huelva
Uruguay, Barcelona, Almería

You can also say ve-baja for v and be-alta for b.

Comment: Thanks! So do you have to use a pause, or is a pause just usually there? I was thinking about the ordinary speed of speaking. How would you know if `ubeiache` is't really `UBIH`, or that `ubea` really isn't `VA`? Ordinarily, would you say e.g. `ve-baja` and `be-alta` when (or whenever) you say the letters in an acronym?

Comment: @Rethliopuks stress tells you a lot.  VIH is /úbeíáche/ and UBIH is /úbéíáche/

Comment: The pause comes naturally, and as @guifa says, stress is important, but these may be difficult for inexperienced speakers to catch. Context, of course, helps a lot, too. So in FBI there's usually no need to say be-alta.